Integrating Monaco editor in nx mono repo mfe in angular
I'm trying to integrate Monaco editor in nx mono repo MFE in angular. But I'm getting some errors related to the loader.
Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type,currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
|

.quick-input-widget {
}

I think this is happening because of the following reason :
The issue I'm encountering with the Monaco Editor is due to Webpack not being configured with the appropriate loaders to parse CSS files.
Solution I tried :

Installed following :
npm install --save-dev css-loader style-loader postcss-loader

Updated webpack.config.ts file to :


    import { withModuleFederation } from '@nx/angular/module- 
    federation';
    import config from './module-federation.config';
    import { Configuration } from 'webpack';
    
    const baseConfig = withModuleFederation(config);
    
    const customConfig: Configuration = {
      ...baseConfig,
      module: {
        ...baseConfig.module,
        rules: [
          ...(baseConfig.module?.rules || []),
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
            use: [
              'style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                  postcssOptions: {
                    plugins: [
                      // Add PostCSS plugins here if needed
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            test: /\.module\.css$/,
            use: [
              'style-loader',
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  modules: true,
                },
              },
              {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                  postcssOptions: {
                    plugins: [
                      // Add PostCSS plugins here if needed
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    };
    
    export default customConfig;

How to fix this issue?
Any help would be appreciated!!
